# Чтение данных с arduino uno через COM порт

Tags: c#, arduino

Доброе время суток! Возникла проблема: код на arduino нормально работает, во встроенном мониторе порта данные правильно отображаются. Но в приложении на C#, особенно очень часто в самом начале приходит непонятных мусор вместо значений.
Типичные значения во встроенном мониторе:

> 145
>
> 0
>
> 145
>
> 0

Значения в программе на C#:

> SSH(??j - откуда берутся эти строки?
>
> 145
>
> 143
>
> ??j

Код программы

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    SerialPort sp = new SerialPort("COM3", 115200, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        sp.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(OnDataReceived);
        sp.Open();
    }

    private void OnDataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(delegate()
            {
                this.console.Text += sp.ReadExisting();
            }));

    }

    private void ReadPort(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void readButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

}

Comment: 145 отправляется из arduino как цифра или как строка? Использовал похожую программу и всё работало нормально. Была одна проблема связанная с неправильной настройкой скорости. В программе было 115200, а в скетче на контроллере 9600.

Comment: как цифра отправляется, скорости стоят одинаковые

Comment: `sp.ReadExisting()` возвращает строку, но это не значит, что числовые значения автоматически преобразуются в строковые. [SerialPort.ReadExisting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.ports.serialport.readexisting(v=vs.110).aspx) Может стоит попробовать какой-нибудь метод Read или ReadByte.

Comment: я разобрался с проблемой, все дело было в том что код на arduino слал слишком много данных в порт и поэтому, видать происходили какие-то сбои

Comment: @MoHcTpUk, опишите, пожалуйста, найденное вами решение в виде ответа. вполне вероятно, что эта информация будет полезна не только вам.

Comment: Много тут неизвестных. Писать в ком порт могут и некоторый модули ардуино подключённые к нему, к примеру карты памяти и модуль BT. Не говоря уже о каких-либо других, менее известных. 

У ардуинно всего один RX\TX (Serial) на всю плату и все модули.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Много работал с компортом и ардуиной. Тагер(для лезертага) делал и прочее. Как я понял мусор в компорте - это вообще норма. Собственно для этого и существуют различные протоколы передачи данных. В простейшем случае, ты должен сначала слать идентификатор начала данных. Это может быть что угодно. Допустим [StartData]. Следом шлешь данные. А после идентификатор конца данных. [StopData]. Не плохо бы еще прикрутить контрольную сумму(гугли по CRC) и длину данных. 
Тогда в с# ты будешь сначала искать в потоке компорта идентификатор начала пакета. Потом читать ответ до идентификатора конца пакета.

Реализовывать чтение можно по-байтово. Считываем байт - если равен '[', то читаем дальше, если следующий 'S' то продолжаем. Нет - отбрасываем, начинаем сначала.

Comment: Примерчик https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/692635/arduino-com-port/692657#692657