# Arduino Com Port

Tags: arduino, com-порт

Возникла идея для разминки сделать проект, суть которого заключается в следующем - принимаю пару чисел (a и b) и число c.
В зависимости от значения c, a и b суммируются (если c=0)
Или вычитаются, если c=1
Проблема в том, что скетч не принимает значения и не вычисляет. Во всяком случае не выдаёт результат. Прошу помочь советом и анализом. Прикрепляю код

```
  void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("I'm ready");
  Serial.println("Input a,b and operation");
  Serial.println("Code operation");
  Serial.println(" 0 - get summary");
  Serial.println(" 1 - get negative");
}
int k;
int a,b,c;

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:


  a = Serial.read();
  b =Serial.read();
  c = Serial.read();
  if (c==0)
  {
    Serial.print("Result= ");
    Serial.println(a+b);
  }
   if (c==1)
  {
    Serial.print("Result= ");
    Serial.println(a-b);
  }

  Serial.println("end loop");
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//#Ulin Project

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    Serial.println("INIT OK");
}

void loop() {    
    while(Serial.read() != '~');
    while(Serial.available() < 3);

    //command on

    byte i0 = (byte)Serial.read();
    byte i1 = (byte)Serial.read();
    byte i2 = (byte)Serial.read();

    if(i0 == '1')Serial.println("0-OK");
    else Serial.println("0-?");

    if(i1 == '1')Serial.println("1-OK");
    else Serial.println("1-?");

    if(i2 == '1')Serial.println("2-OK");
    else Serial.println("2-?");

    int symma = byteToInt(i0)+byteToInt(i1)+byteToInt(i2);
    Serial.print("+:");
    Serial.println(symma);

}

int byteToInt(byte a){
  if(a == '0')return 0;  
  if(a == '1')return 1;  
  if(a == '2')return 2; 
  if(a == '3')return 3; 
  if(a == '4')return 4; 
  if(a == '5')return 5; 
  if(a == '6')return 6;
  if(a == '7')return 7;
  if(a == '8')return 8;
  if(a == '9')return 9;
  return 0;
}
```

!!!Входные данные должны начинатся с ~ . Для стабильности.

**Test0:**

Ввод:

```
~101
```

Вывод:

```
INIT OK 
0-OK 
1-?
2-OK 
+:2
```

**Test2:**

Ввод:

`~999`

Вывод:

```
0-? 
1-? 
2-? 
+:27
```

**Test Online:** https://www.tinkercad.com/things/4miWjU1NSi8-smooth-jarv-blorr

*Я предоставил простой пример как сравнивать байты которые приходят из Serial, написал небольшой протакол который в случае ~111 Вернет 3 ok. А также написал пример сложения цифр путем приведения из байта в int.*

Comment: Это же C++.
int byteToInt(char ch) {
   return ch-'0';
}

Comment: Посмотрите, я описал функцию снизу. функция проста. так как сравнивает просто байты.. а аски кодировкой.