# В ком. порт приходят нe те значения

Tags: c#, c++, arduino

Мне необходимо собрать некую программу для управления светом и т.д. в комнате (при помощи ардуино).
Суть в чём: первая фотка - макет самой программы.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
   При нажатии на кнопку-должен отправляться протокол на ардуино через ком. порт, для подтверждения изменения состояния.

вторая фотка -  пример отправки данных

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

(при нажатии на кнопку, отправляется массив байт ), а вот на ардуинку приходит не пойми что
 - третья фотка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в чём проблема ? и четвёртая фотка, на всякий случай, то как я принимаю данные с ком. порта на стороне с++.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Буду очень благодарен если подскажете почему отправляются не те значения и если можно, то "Простым языком";[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: для начала, не совсем понятно, как работает RawSerialize

Comment: И отладчиком не забудьте посмотреть что находится в byteArray перед отправкой в порт.

Comment: (=__=)  отправляете массив в 5 байт, а принимаете в 4х-байтовый INT

Comment: Добавил описание RawSerialize и проверил через программу сниффер что отправляется в com port

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Чтение данных с arduino uno через COM порт](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/429475/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%81-arduino-uno-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-com-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82)

Comment: Поддерживаю Alias. Читайте байты (char) а не int числа.

Comment: Ещё хорошо бы код из картинок перевести в текст.

Comment: 1)что есть `Slid`, ваша структура/класс? приведите её код;    
2)почему-то в сниффанных байтах я не вижу остальных вводимых значений (КМК, этих 5 байт просто не хватило) => в среде разработки в исходном коде поставьте брейкпойнт на `sp.Open();` и из отладчика покажите что в массиве `byteArray` будет в момент прихода на брейкпойнт.

Comment: @test123 не принципиально канешн, но вроде в C++ есть тип без/знаковый `byte`, для именно числовых операций лучше сразу определиться.

Comment: @Alias, из коробки есть только char. BYTE, byte, Byte, и прочие байтовые типы - это библиотечные define-ы, либо велосипеды операционных систем, которые, так или иначе, используют char.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в том, что размер структуры на стороне с# не соответствует ее реальному размеру. У меня в структуре переменны были int, а как оказалось int занимает 2 байта. Заменил на byte и всё заработало.

Comment: [RTFM, please (=__=)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/s3f49ktz.aspx)